# Firebase Security Rules for a collection named "documents"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to put some security rules in my Firestore database.
For all of my collections, it works like a charm.
Except one: a collection named "documents".

There is any known limitation about this?

Thanks!

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // kind of custom validations...

    function isPartOfGroup1() {
      return request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.group == 'group1';
    }
    function isPartOfGroup2() {
      return request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.group == 'group2';
    }

    // those rules didn't work:

    match /documents/{documents}/{document=**} {
      allow get: if isPartOfGroup1();
      allow list: if isPartOfGroup1();
      allow create: if isPartOfGroup1();
      allow update: if isPartOfGroup1();
      allow delete: if isPartOfGroup1();
    }

    // for example, rules that works:

    match /poll/{poll}/{document=**} {
      allow get: if isPartOfGroup1() || isPartOfGroup2();
      allow list: if isPartOfGroup1() || isPartOfGroup2();
      allow create: if isPartOfGroup1();
      allow update: if isPartOfGroup1();
      allow delete: if isPartOfGroup1();
    }

    //...

  }
}
```

The result in the web console:

Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: Please edit the question to include enough information so that anyone can reproduce the problem exactly as you're seeing it.  This includes showing queries, data, and any other setup that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Correct me if I am wrong. I think the collection name `documents` is affecting the security rules as the path to the collection would be `/databases/{database}/documents/documents` in this case.

Comment: Please edit the question as requested.  Anyone should be able to reproduce the issue given your instructions. If you think there's a bug in the security rule system, please file a bug with Firebase support.  https://www.sfgate.com/travel/resources/airports/article/Nearly-400-flights-cancelled-delayed-sfo-runway-14423170.php